# Network issue with windows

Tags: windows-10, networking, firefox, proxy, firewall

Really don't know how to explain this but there are some strange things happening with my Windows  10.

Everything with my internet is fine because i am able to use it. But

- My windows store apps are not updating they are stuck at loading only.
- My Windows updates are not installing they are also stuck at loading.
- I am able to connect with Unity store but cannot download anything from there.
- I am not able to make any http requests from any unity application.
- I am not able to install firefox with executable it just shows there were some errors and asks to try again later.
- Some sites show proxy error but the are working for others ( I asked my friend).
- I deployed my website on AWS. Everyone is able to use it but not me. It shows proxy error.

I am facing these issues from a long time but now i suspect these issues are linked. There is something which is there with my firewall or something like that. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

- I am able to access sites showing proxy error with Tor Browser.
- I am not using any Proxy and no authentication is being asked.
- Its a wired connection.

Comment: What exact “proxy error“ are you seeing? Are you aware you are using a proxy? Do you have to use a proxy? Does the proxy require authentication?

Comment: Are you connected on wired or wireless

Comment: I have updated the question based on your comments

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset and DNS Flush:   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer and test.

Comment: Done with resetting TCP/IP and flushing DNS but still same issues is there.